# Extracting generic rest properties of an object interface

Tags: typescript

The following code results in an error, because according to TypeScript the type `Pick<Test<T>, Exclude<keyof T, "someKey">>` is not assignable to `T`. When I reason about this type it should be assignable to `T`, is there anyway to get TypeScript to agree with me? Or is this just pushing the boundaries of generic typing in TypeScript, since a variant which isn't dynamically typed will compile correctly.

```js
type Test<T = {}> = T & {
  someKey: string
};

function extract<T>(props: Test<T>): T {
  const {someKey, ...rest} = props;
  return rest;
}
```

And the full TS error message

```
Type 'Pick<Test<T>, Exclude<keyof T, "someKey">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: If `T` is `{ someKey: string }` and `...rest` is implicity `{}` and your function asserts a return type of `T`, then the structures clearly do not match.

Comment: But even when omitting the object literal (`{}`) as the implicit type of `T` the types will not check?

Comment: `{} & { someKey: string }` is always `{ someKey: string }`. Omitting `{}` has no effect on your intersection type.

Comment: Consider replacing `Test<T = {}> = T & { someKey: string; }` with `Test<T = { k1: string; k2: number; k3: boolean }> = T & { someKey: string }`. The resulting type is will still be `{ someKey: string; }`. Hopefully someone more experienced can shed some light.

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is actually right in this case.

Suppose you have some type `A`:

```
type A = {
    someKey: string;
    someOtherKey: string;
}
```

Then, your `extract<A>` will remove the key `someKey` and return something of the type

```
{
    someOtherKey: string;
}
```

which will not by assignable to `A`.

Comment: In my example `T` is intersected with `{ someKey: string }`, which I would assume corresponds to a type which would in a mental model look something like this: `{ ...T, someKey: string }`. Maybe I am making some faulty assumptions about the behavior of intersection types though?

Comment: @Matthisk That's roughly correct, but if `T` already has `someKey: string`, then `{ ...T, someKey: string }` is just `{ ...T }`, or `T`, so once you've taken away the `someKey` you no longer have `T` at all.

Comment: That makes sense, so when I adapt the return type of `exclude` to be `Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, "someKey">>` it will compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try modeling your function this way:

```
interface Some {
  someKey: string;
}

function extract<T extends Some>(props: T): Subtract<T, Some> {
  const { someKey, ...rest } = props;

  return rest;
}

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type Subtract<T, U> = Omit<T, keyof U & keyof T>;
```

Usage:

```
extract({ someKey: 'foo', foo: 1, bar: 2 }); // $ExpectType { foo: number, bar: number }
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Some%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someKey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20extract%3CT%20extends%20Some%3E(props%3A%20T)%3A%20Subtract%3CT%2C%20Some%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20%7B%20someKey%2C%20...rest%20%7D%20%3D%20props%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20rest%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Omit%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20T%2C%20K%3E%3E%3B%0D%0Atype%20Subtract%3CT%2C%20U%3E%20%3D%20Omit%3CT%2C%20keyof%20U%20%26%20keyof%20T%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aextract(%7B%20someKey%3A%20'foo'%2C%20foo%3A%201%2C%20bar%3A%202%20%7D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%24ExpectType%20%7B%20foo%3A%20number%2C%20bar%3A%20number%20%7D%0D%0A).